# Best practices for using the SendInput API

Tags: c++, winapi, sendinput

I am working on an automated testing library, and want to simulate mouse and keyboard inputs using the [SendInput Win32 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This API allows one to push several input items in a single call to the API. There are a number of other examples and similar libraries throughout the web using SendInput. Many of them pass a single input operation for each call to the API. Is there any advantage to batching inputs, or using a single input per call to SendInput? The documentation doesn't seem to offer guidance, or perhaps I'm misreading it.

Comment: The only hint I was able to read out of the documentation was this: _"These events are not interspersed with other keyboard or mouse input events."_ So if you are sending key **combinations** it is probably best to send them in a single batch to prevent other input events to mash up the keyboard state.

Comment: By far the best practice is to **not** use SendInput.  Use the existing support for UI Automation.  Like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee684009%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant: this really depends on what you are trying to do. UIA has only fairly basic support for UI manipulation, and there are some cases where it is not consistent with the same operation carried out via mouse/keyboard. A common pattern for test automation is to use UIA to read and verify UI state is as expected before and after an operation, and to determine the location of target UI element, but to use SendInput to perform the actual manipulation. Also, some types of input operations - hotkeys, or custom mouse events such as dragging - are not supported by UIA so require SendInput.

Comment: @Tim: that's not really much of a concern for test automation, where the environment is somewhat controlled, and you generally don't have to worry about a user providing input that could interfere with the test while the test is running. A macro playback utility, on the other hand, would have to worry about an impatient or naive user and take that into account. (Using [BlockInput()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646290(v=vs.85).aspx) is another way to do this.)

Comment: @BrendanMcK: I appreciate your insights. I do have to worry about multiple windows in the application being automated, but that's another story altogether. I'd already considered `BlockInput()` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no real benefit to one technique vs the other that I know of. In either case, the usual potential problem with SendInput is that the input focus could change between when you send the input and when the input is received by the target application. The classic example is a modal dialog appearing asynchronously to alert the user of some problem, and ends up stealing focus, and soaking up the remaining input that was supposed to go elsewhere. There's no difference between doing a successive series of SendInputs vs a single SendInput in this scenario.

(I'm pretty sure that internally, SendInput is just looping over the inputs passed to it anyway...)